# Directory "diff"?

Tags: command-line

I have two directories which are different versions of the same software package.  I'd like to list all the files/directories that have changed between the two then copy those differences to a new directory.

I've been trying different scripts with `md5sum` and `diff -Nurq` but haven't been able to get the result I'm looking for.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What does it mean to "copy a difference"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `diff -r` (or variations) gives you the differences already. What are you trying to do with them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `rsync` instead.  Something like `rsync -rv $old/ $new/` should do the trick: this will print the files it's going to copy over.

Run with additional `-n` for a dry-run before actually modifying the new directory.

Answer (score 5):

The best tool that I have found is using vim with the [DirDiff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102) plugin. If you use `vim` and `vimdiff`, this Plugin will be easy to learn.

The author describes it this way:

> **description**
>
> This is a utility that performs a
>   recursive diff on two directories and
>   generate a diff "window".  Based on
>   that window you can perform various
>   diff operations such as opening two
>   files in Vim's diff mode, copy the
>   file or directory recursively to the
>   other, or remove the directory tree
>   from the source directory.

DirDiff is like using `vimdiff` to compare two directories, and all subdirectories and files contained therein. I use this tool often for comparing different Subversion branches, configuration directories on different hosts, etc.

For a screenshot, look at dedm's blog: http://dedm.livejournal.com/115224.html