# How do I save changed files?

Tags: rsync, diff, file-copy

I have two folders:

```
ORIGINAL/
ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES/
```

My friend has a copy of `ORIGINAL/`. I would like to generate `MY_CHANGES.tgz` -- it should contain only new/changed files from `ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES/` comparing to `ORIGINAL/`. So my friend can unpack it into his copy of `ORIGINAL/` and get `ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES/`.

How can I do this?

P.S. I tried `diff` but it can't save binary data and `rsync --link-dest` -- it generates hard links which are useless in the archive.

P.P.S. In my case modification time can't be used to decide which file was changed.

Comment: Did you look at the [Directory “diff”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/directory-diff) question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### With rsync

What you're doing is essentially an incremental backup: your friend (your backup) already has the original files, and you want to make an archive containing the files you've changed from that original.

[Rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) has features for incremental backups.

```
cd ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGED
rsync -a -c --compare-dest=../ORIGINAL . ../CHANGES_ONLY
```

- `-a` means to preserve all attributes (times, ownership, etc.).
- `-c` means to compare file contents and not rely on date and size.
- `--compare-dest=/some/directory` means that files which are identical under that directory and the source tree are not copied. Note that the path is relative to the destination directory.

Rsync copies all directories, even if no files end up there. To get rid of these empty directories, run `find -depth CHANGES_ONLY -type d -empty -delete` (or if your `find` doesn't have `-delete` and `-empty`, run `find -depth CHANGES_ONLY -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null`).

Then make the archive from the `CHANGES_ONLY` directory.

#### The pedestrian way

Traverse the directory with your file. Skip files that are identical with the original. Create directories in the target as necessary. Copy changed files.

```
cd ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES
find . \! -type d -exec sh -c '
  for x; do
    if cmp -s "$x" "../ORIGINAL/$x"; then continue; fi
    [ -d "../CHANGES_ONLY/$x" ] || mkdir -p "../CHANGES_ONLY/${%/*}"
    cp -p "$x" "../CHANGES_ONLY/$x"
  done
' {} +
```

Comment: It's even better solution than enzotib's because I can put MY_CHANGES in source control and update/track these changes (if I update rsync's batch file under source control it'll be impossible to see what files were changed)

Comment: @Dmitry If you're using source control, why not put import/track `ORIGINAL` and make `ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES` a branch? Then find out `CHANGES` with an scm command.

Comment: In my case `ORIGINAL` it's Android platform sources (3GB, 126000 files). Even running rsync takes ~15-20 minutes. I think that adding all this stuff under source control will take too much space and time.

Comment: @Dmitry That settles it then. If it's Android sources, use repo and git. Work on your own branch. It's hard enough managing those with version control, I shudder to think what it may be like without it. Fortunately git is very good at managing local branches.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a custom Android sources without any repo/git repositories in it.

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
rsync --only-write-batch=FILE $other_options ORIGINAL_AND_MY_CHANGES/ ORIGINAL/
```

would produce a batch FILE containing the changes required (without modifying anything).

The patch could be applied on another site, where you take the batch FILE, with

```
rsync --read-batch=FILE ORIGINAL/
```