# How rsync --compare-dest works

Tags: rsync, file-comparison

I know there's a very similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/how-do-you-compare-two-folders-and-copy-the-difference-to-a-third-folder), but the accepted answer has nothing to do with rsync, and the OP's solution doesn't apply in my case.

I'm trying to get all the updates from a CentOS repo that differ from my local repo, by comparing them to a disk backup of the repo:

```
rsync -avh --dry-run --compare-dest=/run/media/user/centos6/updates/x86_64/Packages /home/REPOS/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ updates
```

However, the dry-run shows that all packages will be transferred, not just the new ones.

Doing a different dry-run, as if I was copying from the repo to the disk, only transfers the new packages:

```
rsync -avh --dry-run /home/REPOS/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ /run/media/djones/centos6/updates/x86_64/Packages
```

So rsync is clearly able to differentiate the new files, but for some reason the compare-dest option still doesn't seem to work.

The quick and dirty solution would be to simply dump a file list using the second command, and then feed that to rsync. But I'd really like to do this the "right" way.

Comment: So in your first `rsync`, you're wanting to copy everything from `/home/REPOS/.../Packages/` to the local folder `updates`. But exclude the copy for files that are found under `/run/media/.../Packages/`?

Comment: Are you sure that http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104265/100397 doesn't solve your question?

Comment: @roaima That's correct.

Comment: @roaima Yes, I tried the OPs method in that post, and it doesn't work. The time stamps are identical for all the common files between the two directories. Besides, it takes a very long time to compute all the checksums.

Comment: what do you want to have? you have 3 dirs source, dest i compare. rsync --compare-desc will copy all files that was changed between source and compare and do not change anything in compare.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble, you have to do:

```
rsync -avh --dry-run                                          \
      --compare-dest=/run/media/user/centos6/updates/x86_64/  \
      /home/REPOS/6/updates/x86_64/Packages                   \
      /path/to/updates
```

**Note** `--compare-dest` is the parent of `Packages` and do not put `/` at the end of source folder!

Answer (score 1):

you need something like that:
`rsync --compare-dest=$local_repo/ $centos_repo/ $differences/`
(define folders to variables or change variables to your paths, paths must be ended by /)
`$differences` might be changed to current data or something like that.

It copy differences inside folders that was between centos_repo and local_repo (centos_repo is source) to differences folder. It make whole dirs tree but insert only changed files in differences.

---

If someone use it for backup, must remember that file which was deleted in source (centos_repo) and exist in compare (local_repo) is not copied to differences

Answer (score 0):

rsync is not only inspecting content when deciding if files are "identical". For this to work correctly, you should sometimes use flags like "--no-times" (this oneworked for me in one occasion), or "--no-perms", "--no-owner", "--no-group, "--checksum", etc.

(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139188/rsync-compare-dest-does-not-work)