# Use rsync to compare a remote directory with a local one, and store differences to another local directory

Tags: files, rsync, file-copy, diff, file-comparison

My problem is similar to the one described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/how-do-you-compare-two-folders-and-copy-the-difference-to-a-third-folder). I want to compare a directory to another, and store the differences in a third one. The difference is that in my case the first directory is on a remote server, and `--compare-dest` does not seem to work with remote directories.

What I tried is

```
rsync -vain --compare-dest=remote-host:/home/gerry/test/ /home/gerry/test/ /home/gerry/testDiff/
```

But I 'm getting an error like this:

```
--compare-dest arg does not exist: remote-host:/home/gerry/test/
```

Am I doing it wrong or isn't it possible at all?

Comment: Cannot you mount the remote host locally (sftp mount) so it is going to be seen as local dir by rsync? More in general you should consider Unison: https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/index.php

Comment: This is interesting but sadly no, sftp mount is not an option in my case.